# Can't set isdeleted through Heroku Connect

Tags: heroku, heroku-connect

I have a postgres database on my heroku instance tied to various salesforce custom objects. Whenever I write true to the isdeleted field in my table everything is fine. However, after it syncs with salesforce the isdeleted is written back as false. Is there some way to set this field?

Comment: If you're trying to *delete* a record, you need to *delete* the record.

Comment: I was told that wouldn't work and it would just come back when salesforce synced. That was apparently wrong, and this is all I needed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IsDeleted field is a system field and we cannot update this field.This field is automatically set when the record is  moved to the Recycle Bin (true) or not (false).

You can find more details in below link:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/system_fields.htm

You can try to map your field with a custom field and do your operations with that custom field.

Comment: while not the true solution the problem that spawned the question, it is the correct answer to the question. Thanks.